# JQuery code working properly in jsfiddle but not in browser even with $(window).load(function())

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I'm trying to make a search using a dropdown list, which will show/hide some checkboxes depending on the chosen answer. The problem is that it works perfectly on jsfiddle.net but refuses to load properly on my local machine. I saw a similar post and said something about adding $(window).load(function()) before the rest of the script, but even then it refused to work. I might be doing something wrong so any help is appreciated.

The link for jsfiddle is this: http://jsfiddle.net/CDyZf/66/

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(window).load(function());
$('.drop-down-show-hide').hide();

$('#dropDown').change(function () {
$(this).find("option").each(function () {
    $('#' + this.value).hide();
});
$('#' + this.value).show();

});
</script>
```

Comment: Tried using `$(document).ready()` ? Also your `load()` function is not wrapping the rest of the js

Comment: Or try wrapping the $(window).load(function( ... code drop here ... )); Or simply add your code before </body>

Comment: do I add $(document).ready() in the beginning of the script? Sorry for asking such a stupid question but I'm new to this.

Comment: $(window).load(function() { * Copy and paste the script from the fiddle here * });

Comment: I fixed the error in the syntax of the load() and put the code inside, but again it wouldn't show properly. I moved it first just before the body as Robert suggested and it worked. Then I tried using the way Quentin said and worked after I fixed some conflicting issues. So thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The argument of `load()` needs to be *a function*.

`load(function())` would pass it the *return value* of calling a function called `function`, if `function` wasn't a reserved word making it a error.

```
function init() {

    $('.drop-down-show-hide').hide();

    $('#dropDown').change(function () {
    $(this).find("option").each(function () {
        $('#' + this.value).hide();
    });
    $('#' + this.value).show();

}

$(window).load( init );
```

Comment: I used your suggestion and it worked up to a point but it was conflicting with something in my code, so I changed it and it worked.